# Python3 [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] Unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, python3, ssl, certificates, https

Encountering below error when attempting to run a program:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1454, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/erik/.local/bin/whisper", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('whisper==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'whisper')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/erik/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 304, in cli
    model = load_model(model_name, device=device, download_root=model_dir)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/erik/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/__init__.py", line 102, in load_model
    checkpoint_file = _download(_MODELS[name], download_root, in_memory)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/erik/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/__init__.py", line 49, in _download
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as source, open(download_target, "wb") as output:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)>
```

Have tried many different things, including exporting system certificate store, reinstalling certifi and Python itself, and manually importing the PEM and CRT files. Nothing has worked so far. Python version is 3.11.1

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you change the default python version (bad idea) or are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: What is the certificate you're working with?  Is it self-signed, or is it signed by some internal CA that your system has not got in its certificate store?  Are you trying to work with a certificate CA that you created yourself?  This behavior in Python is *typical* when working with untrusted CAs or self-signed certificates.

Comment: Ubuntu version is 20.04. I am not using a virtual environment. This is a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Have verified that there are no issues with openssl, python, or pip.